# How to add a submenu to the right side of an existing menu line item, using CSS

Tags: css

I have a small rectangular menu situated halfway down inside a page, away from the window top.  The full HTML for that:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML dir=ltr xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<HEAD>
  <META content="IE=8.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <TITLE>Submenu Attempt</TITLE>
  <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <META http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=8>
  <META http-equiv=Content-Style-Type content=text/css>
  <META http-equiv=Content-Script-Type content=text/javascript>

  <LINK href="tasks.css" rel=Stylesheet type=text/css media=screen>

  <META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 11.00.9600.19003">
</HEAD>

<BODY class="no-js home home" id=00>
<DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff">
  </DIV></DIV>

  <DIV class=container-backdrop 
    style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(); BACKGROUND-REPEAT: no-repeat; BACKGROUND-POSITION: center 50%">
  </DIV>

  <DIV class=backdrop-mask></DIV>
  <DIV class=container-content id=01 style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px">

  <DIV class=container-top-tasks style="FONT-FAMILY: Calibri; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; TEXT-ALIGN: left; FILTER: alpha(opacity=80)">
    <H2 style="FONT-WEIGHT: normal"><STRONG style="FONT-FAMILY: Calibri; FONT-WEIGHT: 400"><B>To Do:</B></STRONG></H2>
    <UL class=top-tasks>
      <LI><A href="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Task 1</A></LI>
      <LI><A href="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Task 2</A></LI>
      <LI><A href="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Task 3</A></LI>
      <LI><A href="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Task 4</A></LI>
    </UL>
  </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

A style sheet, called tasks.css, formats that menu:

```
.container-top-tasks H2 {
    FONT-FAMILY: "MetaWebBold"; WORD-SPACING: 1px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; LETTER-SPACING: -1px; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.1em
}
UL.top-tasks LI {
    FONT-WEIGHT: normal
}
UL.top-tasks A:after {
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold
}
UL.top-tasks A:after {
    FONT-SIZE: 2em
}
.container-top-tasks H2 {
    FONT-SIZE: 1.4em
}
UL.top-tasks LI {
    FONT-SIZE: 1.2em
}
UL.top-tasks A {
    FONT-SIZE: 0.75em
}
UL.top-tasks A {
    TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
UL.top-tasks A {
    LINE-HEIGHT: 150%
}
UL.top-tasks A:after {
    LINE-HEIGHT: 0.4em
}
.container-top-tasks H2 {
    MARGIN: 0px
}
.container-top-tasks H2:after {
    MARGIN: 0px
}
UL.top-tasks {
    MARGIN: 0px
}
.container-top-tasks H2:after {
    DISPLAY: block
}
UL.top-tasks A {
    DISPLAY: block
}
UL.top-tasks A:after {
    DISPLAY: block
}
.container-top-tasks {
    POSITION: relative
}
UL.top-tasks A {
    POSITION: relative
}
.container-top-tasks H2:after {
    FLOAT: right
}
UL.top-tasks A:after {
    FLOAT: right
}
UL.top-tasks A {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #15678a
}
UL.top-tasks A:hover {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #104f69
}
.container-top-tasks H2:after {
    FLOAT: right
}
UL.top-tasks A:after {
    FLOAT: right
}
.container-content {
    WIDTH: 954px; MARGIN: -263px auto 52px
}
.container-top-tasks {
    WIDTH: 24%; MARGIN: 0px 0px 55px auto
}
.container-top-tasks H2 {
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 14px; PADDING-LEFT: 16px; PADDING-RIGHT: 16px
}
.container-top-tasks H2:after {
    HEIGHT: 25px; WIDTH: 26px
}
UL.top-tasks {
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px
}
UL.top-tasks A {
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; PADDING-TOP: 4px; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; MARGIN: 1px; PADDING-RIGHT: 16px
}
UL.top-tasks A:after {
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 4px; CONTENT: "\203A"; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px
}
.container-backdrop {
    MIN-HEIGHT: 454px
}
.home {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #262a2e
}
.container-top-tasks {
    BACKGROUND: #2098cd; -pie-background: linear-gradient(#E52532, #B0141B); background-size: auto 100%
}
UL.top-tasks A:after {
    MARGIN-BOTTOM: 4pt; VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; COLOR: #3399ff; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; MARGIN-TOP: 0px
}
.container-top-tasks H2 {
    COLOR: #fff
}
UL.top-tasks A {
    COLOR: #fff
}
UL.top-tasks A {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #15678a
}
UL.top-tasks A:hover {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #104f69
}
```

I cannot figure out how to add a submenu that emerges off the right side of that--for example's sake, next to "Task 2"--that would have like a "Subtask A" and "Subtask B" (the latter two stacked above each other, with "Subtask A" coming directly laterally to the right off of "Task 2").  A mockup to illustrate that:[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty demo based on your mockup image of how to implement a subnavigation using a CSS `:hover` state to expand it.

Essentially, the subnav is another `<ul>` element inside the relevant `<li>`, which is positioned to be 100% offset horizontally, and hidden with `visibility`.

See it in action below:

```css
ul {
  background: #15678a;
  border: 1px solid #2182ad;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2182ad;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: .2em;
  position: relative;
}

.subnav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.has-subnav:hover .subnav {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Task 1</li>
  <li class="has-subnav">
    Task 2 (hover me)
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li>Subtask A</li>
      <li>Subtask B</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Task 3</li>
  <li>Task 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've accepted the answer as final, but I can't integrate the CSS code into the existing menu.  I've posted at bottom-most of the question what I'm able to achieve.  I'm mystified by how to proceed.

Comment: @ni37osllb Is there any part of my demo that you are having trouble understanding? Can you please put all of your code in a JSFiddle and share the link here so I can see what's going on?

Comment: I don't know CSS files.  It's all Greek to me.  I added something to the bottom of the CSS file that's already on this site page.  (See above.)  I wish I could run with a quick and dirty example, but unfortunately I have no CSS file education to make successful extrapolations from it.